# how to return user from django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 convert token view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am currently using Django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 and it's convert-toke endpoint. I send user token from Facebook with the request to this end point which on success, responds with the following data:

```
{
  "access_token": "************",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 36000,
  "refresh_token": "************",
  "scope": "read write"
}
```

However, I also want to get the id of authenticated user, So I tried using `request.user` in the custom view,  but it always return AnonymousUser.

```
class SocialView(ConvertTokenView):


 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        response = super(SocialView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**EDIT:**

I found a way, I can retrieve user through the access_token from the response.

```
user = AccessToken.objects.get(token=response.data['access_token'])
```

but I am not sure if it's correct way to do that?

Comment: Well, I found a way and I retrieved the user using access_token from response `user = AccessToken.objects.get(token=response.data['access_token'])`, but am not sure if it is the right way?

Answer (score 1):

`AccessToken` retrieved is an instance of the actual access token and it has a user property.

```
token = AccessToken.objects.get(token=response.data['access_token'])
user = token.user
```

#### Reference

- https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/models.py#L230